# Setting push notification service iOS. Missing .certSigningRequest file

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate

I have an app which is already in AppStore. In this version I haven't include Push Notification Service and in my AppID this setting was disabled.

Now I need to upload new version of app with **push notifications**.

For this I followed [Ray's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) but I don't have **.certSigningRequest** file.

How to include APNS to my new version of app? What I should do in such case?

Comment: If u followed tuto then u got certSigningRequest in step "Generating the Certificate Signing Request (CSR)" not?

Comment: I can not generate it, cuz it's not new app... and i'm afraid to break something

Comment: did you solve it,I encountered the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't be afraid. Just generate CSR with help of KeyChain and after that update your appID in developer program. Download provision profile and you'll get profit.
You can't break anything.

Comment: what about my old version which already in the Store? Does users can work with now available old version?